# Scotch Box vagrant box not accessible trough browser anymore

Tags: apache, vagrant, virtualbox

Im quite new to Vagrant using it for a year now without troubles. Using scotch box and it always worked like a charm on my Win10 pc. Never had the need to dive deeper into Vagrant or the setup.

Yesterday I started my Vagrant box like every day and it just did not work anymore.

- vagrant up seems to work without troubles
- I can ssh into my box, shared folder is available under /var/ww like usual
- I go with my browser to the 192.168.33.10 ... connection timeout

`VirtualBox VM 5.0.14 r105127 win.amd64`

vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
        config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
        config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
        config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
        config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
        config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
        config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :nfs => { :mount_options =>     ["dmode=777","fmode=666"] }
        config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
            v.memory = 2048
            v.cpus = 2
        end
    end
```

httpd is running and listens to port 80

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1285/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1056/postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46523           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      648/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11300         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1355/beanstalkd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      971/mongod
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1038/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1511/redis-server *
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1502/memcached
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      562/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1285/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::36713                :::*                    LISTEN      648/rpc.statd
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      1511/redis-server *
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      562/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2084/apache2
```

**UPDATE1**

ifconfig gives the desires result

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:97:ff:45
          inet addr:192.168.33.10  Bcast:192.168.33.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe97:ff45/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:89 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:11275 (11.2 KB)  TX bytes:1836 (1.8 KB)
```

After logging in on the ssh and using curl on both localhost and on the right ip i get the expected bahaviour. It seems that apache and php are running ok.

**UPDATE2**

Weird thing happens when i reprovision. Virtualbox creates a new network-adapter every time I reprovision/start Vagrant. Probably need to find the solution in the network adapters?

**UPDATE3**

Voted down directly, please let me know how I can improve my question or provide more data that is useful.

Comment: did you (re)provision the machine ? did you check the status of your firewall in ubuntu ?

Comment: Weird thing happens when i reprovision. Virtualbox creates a new netwok-adapter every time I reprovision the machine. Probably need to find the solution in the network adapters..

Comment: what you mean a new ? how many network adapters do you have ? you still have 2, no ?

Comment: The guest machine has two, the WIN10 host machine creates a new VirtualBox Host-Only Network every time Vagrants starts, reloads or reprovisions.

Comment: I'm sure you've already checked but do your Virtualbox and Guest Addtions versions match up?

Comment: well I don't think it should generate issue - if you restart windows, it might even clean the list. can you access the VM through browser after windows restart, don't think so

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my laptop. Restored windows completely, installed my software and again exactly the same (on a clean install).
Restored my laptop again, installed software one-by-one and found out that it blocked after installing **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013** what was needed for MySQL Workbench.

I changed **MySQL Workbench** for **HeidiSQL** so I did not need the Visual C++ and this solved all my problems.